# conflicting url.sty

Tags: latex2html

This is a minimal example of the problem I am having:

```
\documentclass[iop]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Sample Article Title}
\section{Sample}\label{samplelabel}
This is just to show the problem in \S \ref{samplelabel}
\end{document}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty

 ! LaTeX Error: Command \url already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.102 \newcommand\url{\begingroup \Url}
```

It is working perfectly on another computer that doesn't have latex2html so I assume [this explanation](http://newton.cx/~peter/work/?p=413) is correct. I am just having problems removing the latex2html along with it's conflicting url.sty. When I try

```
tlmgr remove latex2html
```

It says:

```
latex2html: package not present, cannot remove
tlmgr: no packages removed.
```

I should just say that I installed the most recent version of latex2html [from here](http://www.latex2html.org/~latex2ht/current/), and compiled it using the `./configure`, `make` and `make install`

I am relatively new to LaTeX, such that I have never needed to remove a package and tlmgr doesn't seem to work. It would be excellent if someone could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the copy of `url.sty` from `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty`.  Does this work?

Actually, the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/tex/latex/html/` is *not* in the standard TL distribution.  If you installed `latex2html` manually, it might be installed from it...

Comment: Actually, after waiting for about an hour with no reply to the question, I thought a fresh installation of LaTeX would have been faster, especially that I was afraid latex2html might have infected other packages too, that I am not aware of now! So I did it and the problem was fixed! I guess your suggestion of replacing the <code>url.sty</code> would have been useful, but it didn't occur to me; I am a beginner! I will keep this in mind though.